# How to wire this relay (silkscreen in Chinese!)?

Tags: relay, solid-state-relay

I have the following relay and am unsure of how to wire it since the silkscreen is in Chinese :-/ [Datasheet](http://www.foxytronics.com/files/file/39-10a-power-relay-datasheet/).

[image]

I'm finding the datasheet difficult to interpret, but from playing around with my multimeter, I'm thinking the terminal on the right is NO, the middle is the input, and the left is NC. Is that right?

Comment: If you take a pic of the symbols you can get an app for your phone which will convert them into English.

Comment: @TimMottram That's a great idea! I just tried Google Translate and it says left is "NC," middle is "Public," and right is "Normally open." Would you like to make that an answer?

Comment: another idea: http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%BB%A7%E7%94%B5%E5%99%A8
that's the chinese page of relay

Comment: In this context, "Public" is probably a mistranslation of "common".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a pic of the symbols you can get an app for your phone which will convert them into English.

Answer (score 8):

My bet is that it has the same connections as this one (from www.dx.com). Relays are the same, and PCB designers tend to be lazy.

[image]

If you don't trust this, get the [datasheet](http://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CD8QFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mycomkits.com%2Freference%2FSongle_SRD(T73)_Relay.pdf&ei=LwRIU7GtMKiW0AW5qYCoAQ&usg=AFQjCNFSi32NMwx4EbXQwFPndwLxFE5cVQ&sig2=ZN74HXlvmzsZ4It08KFUNg&bvm=bv.64542518,d.d2k) of the relay and trace the tracks on the bottom.

Comment: I can read Chinese and I can confirm the connections in this answer match the Chinese description in the question.

Comment: @Codism if you can have a look at http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/279014/how-to-wire-relay-documented-in-chinese it would be great.