# How to wire relay documented in Chinese?

Tags: relay

I got a sensor based relay and I am unable to understand the purpose of the white wire (coded XF).

For the others I assumed these:
* Connect relay black wire (N) to neutral from the socket (Blue) which is also connected to the Lamp blue wire
* Connect relay red wire (L) to socket wire L (Brown)
* Connect relay yellow line (L0) to lamp brown wire

I tried to use it without connecting the white wire to anything but it doesn't seem to work.

I am inclined to believe that "fire control line (F)" may be the poor translation of ground-wire but I don't want to risk anything.

http://s3.sbarnea.com/ss/Monosnap_2017-01-07_14-33-11.png[image: chinese-relay]

Comment: First you have to learn Chinese.

Comment: Hmm, maybe another time. I tried using google translate and discovered that probably this is how they translated it to Engrish.

Comment: "Fire" is probably a bad translation of "Trigger" - XF then being "E**X**ternal **F**ire (Trigger)". Just a guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Fire control" is probably used to force the lamp to turn on.  Whether you need to connect it to neutral or hot I don't know.  It also isn't clear whether it takes pulse ( push button) or switch on the F input.  It would probably be easier to tell if you would post the full written instructions.

Making it work using the sensor probably requires some adjustment.

It has a light sensor, so that you can adjust it to only work at night, or also to switch on during the daytime.

There are three holes on one end.  Each of them has a little screw slot in it to adjust something.  The top of the device has markings to indicate which hole is for what.

One is marked as a circle that is half black and half white.  That is the day/night adjustment.  Turn it all the way to the white side for daylight operation.

The other two regulate the sensitivity (the waves) and the time the light stays on when triggered.

Once you've set it for daylight operation, you should be able to make it trigger.

Comment: I made it work without using the white wire, I suspect that's for emergency escape light and it would need power. Is like alternative L which goes on in case primary L goes down. Anyway is not needed for home use. Thanks.

Comment: From what I read on a site where they sell the things, XF is an input to make the light turn on regardless of what the sensor says.  It just isn't clear how to use it.  It is optional - the sensor works without it as you've found.

Comment: @sorin from what I have read in Chinese, the "Fire control" is intended to be used in emergence situation. However, I couldn't find what should be the input. Most Chinese sites only said it can be left along if you don't have to. I would guess it can either be a signal to override the sensor status or a backup power that provides power in case of grid down. If I were you, I will open one and figure out:)

Answer (score 1):

According to this image I found [online](https://www.banggood.com/220V-Auto-Motion-Sensor-Sensing-Switch-Microwave-Radar-Sensor-with-Fire-Line-p-1034337.html), the fire line works exactly the way JRE asserts: it's a way to force the lamp to switch on regardless the sensors permissions.
It seems it needs a switch (not pulse) and for sure is connected to the line.

[image: Wiring diagram]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. You should, of course, credit that image by providing a link to the site it came from. Click the "edit" link below your question.